# Sort divs based on custom data attributes via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of divs. Each div contains a custom data attribute called "data-target". The data-target contains numbers. These numbers have nothing to do with the order.

Via Javascript I want to create a list for the right order of the divs.

For example: 
- Where custom attribute is "4321" set position 1. 
- Where custom attribute is "5849" set position 2.
...

Below you can find an example of what I am thinking of, yet it's not working.

**HTML/CSS**

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
}

#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
    <div style="background-color:green;" data-target="111222"> </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;" data-target="222333"> </div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>


function myFunction() {

    $('[data-target="111222"]').style.order = "2";
    $('[data-target="222333"]').style.order = "1";

}


</script>
```

The first div with the green background should switch to the second position. I found a working example here, but the call it by the ElementID and not a custom data attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {

    document.querySelector('div[data-target="111222"]').style.order = "2";
    document.querySelector('div[data-target="222333"]').style.order = "1";

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: flex;
}

#main div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
    <div style="background-color:green;" data-target="111222"> </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;" data-target="222333"> </div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your browser console you should get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'order' of undefined

This means that jQuery object does not have a property called `style` that's why it's treating it like `undefined`. If you want to modify css properties of jQuery objects use **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** instead. Your code should look like:

```
$('div[data-target="111222"]').css('order', '2');
$('div[data-target="222333"]').css('order', '1');
```

Attached a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oew9n31j/)**.